# How to create an 'empty if statement' in python

Tags: python, if-statement

It's very common in C: hacking 'empty if statement' like this:

```
if(mostlyhappencondition)
    ;#empty statement
else{
    dosomething;
}
```

It's working in Python? I mean, can we improve the app's performance by using that? I'd also like to know why.

Comment: It's common in C? It looks like a misguided attempt at optimization to me.

Comment: I was looking for similar coding strategy. The reason is not for optimization but for better readability of the code. Like instead of using `if not some_thing and not some_thing_else: do_something` its better to read code as `if something or something_else: pass else: do_something`. The answers here helped! Thanks.

Comment: even more useful when you just want to put an empty # TODO block

Comment: I can imagine a better readability case when a number of things is tested (validated) in `if-elif[-...]-else` block like in `if some-long-condition: pass elif one-more-long-condition: pass [elif ...] else: return (exit function with) something-like-abrupt-error-message` somewhat similar to what @SourabhBhat- shared. It would be much more convenient than negating the conditions to `return something-like-abrupt-error-message` each and every if or elif.

Comment: The case I explain above seems to me a kind of other languages' switch-case construct with empty broken cases (cases with breaks) and one-for-all default substitute.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is a performance improvement if there isn't an else case in the "if", since the bytecodes don't pass execution into the "if" case.

Here's some functions and the output of `dis.dis(foo)`

The following sample app:

```
def foo(x):
    if x:
        pass
    else:
        return x+2
```

Disassembles to:

```
5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
            3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        9

6           6 JUMP_FORWARD             8 (to 17)

8     >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
           12 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
           15 BINARY_ADD          
           16 RETURN_VALUE        
      >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           20 RETURN_VALUE
```

The following

```
def foo(x):
    if not x:
        return x+2
```

Disassembles to:

```
11           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        14

12           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             9 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
            12 BINARY_ADD          
            13 RETURN_VALUE        
       >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
```

Comment: it's a pretty stupid compiler if it is not able to recognize if an if / else has no code and is just to document code. I hope Python has solved this bug.

Answer (score 33):

I can only guess you're looking for the `pass` statement, sometimes needed to create an empty code block to prevent a syntax error.

```
if mostlyhappencondition:
    pass
else:
    do_something()
```

It would be much more usual to just do this, which is logically equivalent:

```
if not mostlyhappencondition:
    do_something()
```

There are no significant performance gains to be found here.

Comment: There are intelligibility gains when using spectific if/elif/else or try/except.

Answer (score 4):

Till the time you dont have any thing in `if True:` you could do

```
if not mostlyhappenedcondition:
   do something()
```

If you dont have to put any thing in "if" even in future, then it is redundunt in your code.

Answer (score 3):

No, that won’t improve performance. In fact, it doesn’t in C, either. Where did you hear that?

`not`/`!` reads better and should have more or less the same speed.

---

And actually tested with `gcc -O4`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        if(!(i < 900000000)) {
            putchar('.');
        }
    }
}
```

vs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        if(i < 900000000);
        else {
            putchar('.');
        }
    }
}
```

#1 took 6.62 seconds and #2 took 6.64 seconds on my computer.